# Intellij java class diagram, arrows between classes

Tags: java, intellij-idea, diagram

I use Intellij to generate class diagrams from my Java code. 
I'm pretty happy with it.

When I click 'Show Dependencies' I get straight arrows being drawn between classes.

[image]

I then click 'Apply Current Layout (F5)', everything gets reorganized nicely with arrows no longer straight lines but rather going around classes in a neat way

[image]

However every time the diagram redraws itself the arrows go straight again. I need to re-click 'Apply Current Layout (F5)' to make them angle again, which also zooms out of the diagram, which is pretty annoying...

Is there a way to keep the arrows angled after a chart redraw?

Using IntelliJ 14.1.4 on Linux, Build IU-141.1532

Comment: You can create an issue on youtrack. https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA . It's strange that the layout is not applied by default.

Comment: Thanks I will, it does look like a bug. When looking at my big big diagram the following message appears briefly in the bottom status bar: 'Calculating dependencies...' Once this is done the diagram blinks and all arrows are straighten again.

Comment: Created: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-145179

Answer (score 2):

I were working on that problem myself. The solution is easy. File->Settings->(search for "diagrams")-> tick the checkbox "Fit content after Layout"

[image]

This only saves the Layout of the classdiagramm, the dependencies are still straight and there is no way to change their behaviour.